# How to create a Dictionary with Key/Value pairs in angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

Using the concept Dictionary I want to do the following task.

```
1. Closed
2. Open
3. Cancelled
4. Rejected
5. Saved
6. Draft
7. Pending Approval
```

This the different statuses . Now my table is like following

```
 Purchase Order            Status
 PO1                       closed
 PO2                       pending_approval
 PO3                       open
 PO4                       Draft
 PO5                       Cancelled
 PO6                       Rejected
 PO7                       Saved
```

Now I need each **status** in different color using the **badge**

Method to use is dictionary method.

1. Can anybody tell me what is dictionary method?(brief explanation)
2. And Kindly give me the solution too

Comment: What are the colours?

Comment: any colours, but should be different

Comment: I guess the colour corresponds to the status? In addition, what is 'Purchase Order'? There can be as many purchase orders as required, right?

Comment: I mentioned it for explaining. Actually color corresponds to status. The status fetch from API should display with different color of badges. This is the concept. For that I want to use Dictionary method and I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Courtesy from **Konrad Rudolph** [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/30931/76130)

> **`Dictionary`** is the [“correct” name](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/dictionary.html) of the
> interface (= the
> [ADT](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/abstractDataType.html)), i.e.
> an associative container that maps (usually unique) keys to (not
> necessarily unique) values.
>
> To summarize: a *dictionary* is an ADT that maps keys to values. There
> are several possible implementations of this ADT, of which the *hash
> table* is one. `Hash` is a misnomer but in context it’s equivalent to
> a dictionary that is implemented in terms of a hash table.

---

##### Solution 1

Straight forward you can use **[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)** type as recommendation

```js
    //Using Map
    let map = new Map<string, string>();

    map.set("PO1", "closed"); 
    map.set("PO2", "pending_approval");
    map.set("PO3", "open");
    map.set("PO4", "Draft");
    map.set("PO5", "Cancelled");
    map.set("PO6", "Rejected");
    map.set("PO7", "Saved");
    
    //get item
    console.log(map.get('PO1'));
    console.log(map.get('PO5'));
    
    //has item
    console.log(map.has('PO1'));
    console.log(map.has('PO5'));
    
    //delete item
    console.log(map.delete('PO1'));
    console.log(map.delete('PO5'));
```

---

##### Solution 2

But if you want custom additional methods you can also create a Dictionary implementation in typescript like as shown below

```js
    //Using Dictionary
    let dict = new Dictionary();
   
    dict.set("PO1", "closed"); 
    dict.set("PO2", "pending_approval");
    dict.set("PO3", "open");
    dict.set("PO4", "Draft");
    dict.set("PO5", "Cancelled");
    dict.set("PO6", "Rejected");
    dict.set("PO7", "Saved");
    
    //get item
    console.log(map.get('PO1'));
    console.log(map.get('PO5'));

    //has item
    console.log(map.has('PO1'));
    console.log(map.has('PO5'));

    //delete item
    console.log(map.delete('PO1'));
    console.log(map.delete('PO5'));
```

**dictionary.ts**

```js
    export class Dictionary {
      items = {};
      constructor() {
        this.items = {};
      }
      public has(key) {
        return key in this.items;
      }
      public set(key,value) {
        this.items[key] = value;
      }
      public get(key) {
        return this.items[key];
      }
      public delete(key) {
        if( this.has(key) ){
          delete this.items[key]
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arjp6h-2dvrwm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 6):

A **dictionary** is a data type that maps from keys to values, and allows you to get the value for a given key in O(1) time.

In Typescript or Javascript, you can use an Object as a dictionary:

```js
const dictionary = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2'
};

console.log(dictionary['key1']); // outputs 'value1'
```

You can also use the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) type:

```js
const map = new Map<string, number>();
map.set('key1', 100);
map.set('key2', 200);

console.log(map.get('key2')); // outputs 200
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let city : {[index:string]: [string,string]}={};
  city["london"] =["rainy",22];
  city["tehran"]=["sunny",23];
  city["shiraz"]=["cloudy",33];

for(let key in city){
  console.log(`the weather in ${key} is ${city[key][0]} and weather is 
  ${city[key][1]}` )
```